# CSS anchor color change not changing on hover and focus

Tags: css, hover, focus, anchor

I'm trying to get the anchor to change color on active and focus but either my syntax is wrong or the style is being overrided.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="nav active">
     <a href="/">HERE</a>
    </li>
     <div class="dropdown">
      <li class="drop nav active">
        <a href="/about.php">ABOUT</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
       <ul>
         <li>
         <a href="/OTHER.php"><p class="drops">OTHER</p></a>     
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="/THING.php"><p class="drops">THING</p></a>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my css

```
.drop a:hover,
.drop a:focus {
   background:lightgoldenrodyellow !important;
   color:red !important;
}
```

The background changes on hover and focus because of the !important (doesn't work without that) but the color does not change. Just need to make sure I don't have some silly syntax error before looking for conflicts. If it's a conflict and there's some other trick to overide it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. A div cannot be a child of a UL

Answer (score 1):

**Before HTML 5**, `<p>` was a block-level element and `<a>` was inline, the latter should not contain the sooner.

In other words: `<a>` should be inside `<p>`, not the opposite. Perhaps your document is not HTML 5, or at least your browser don't treat it as such. The following code works fine for me:

```css
.drop a:hover,
.drop a:focus {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="nav active">
    <a href="/">HERE</a>
  </li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="drop nav active">
      <a href="/about.php">ABOUT</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p class="drops">
              <a href="/OTHER.php">OTHER</a>
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="drops">
              <a href="/THING.php">THING</a>
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

I have also fixed another syntax error in your HTML code: you forgot `</div>` before the last `</ul>`.

Comment: In HTML 5: The A element is considered as a phrasing element when it
contains phrasing content, and as a flow element when it
contains flow content
Permitted Content is: Phrasing content and flow elements
The p element's permitted parents are: Any element that can contain flow elements.
It's permitted content is Phrasing content

Comment: @Konrud: Good point, I updated my answer accordingly. We don't know though if question's author uses HTML 5 and above code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see no real problem but you can:

change a:focus to a:active or make sure you are including the stylesheet in your html